# How can two alternating characters be output efficiently or without a loop?

Tags: c++, optimization, char, output

It's a bit tricky to explain the question, but suppose two alternating chars must be shown:

```
for(int n=0; n<20; n++)
{
    cout<<(n%2==0 ? 'X' : 'Y');
}
```

Is there a one-liner or more efficient way to accomplish the task above? (i.e. using something like `<iomanip>`'s `setfill()`)?

Comment: I would just use `cout << "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY";`...

Comment: That won't be a viable option, as this is inside a function and "int n " can change to something else. It needs to be scalable.

Comment: In that case, just go with the loop. `cout` will have to loop through each character too, and there's no much you can do about I/O being slow anyway. If this code is the bottleneck in your application, then you have huge problems. If it isn't, then just don't worry about efficiency.

Comment: Well, yeah, this is the only inefficient code; it takes ~150-200 ms to execute (because of the loop) and there are lots of calls to this function.

Comment: @abckookooman interviewer puzzle?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think I'd keep it simple:

```
static const char s[] ="XY";

for (int n=0; n<20; n++)
    std::cout << s[n&1];
```

The other obvious possibility would be to just write out two characters at a time:

```
for (int n=0; n<total_length/2; n++)
    std::cout << "XY";
```

Comment: +1. A note for readers : `std::cout << "XY"[n&1];` would also work and the variable `s` is not really needed.

Comment: I doubt that this is "better" than OP's code. For instance, it's not entirely obvious to read. Better be explicit with the `?:` operator, the compiler will optimize it anyway.

Comment: @H2CO3: If that is not readable enough, then `s[n%2]` is another option, which means `?:` is still not needed. :P

Comment: @H2CO3: I think there's a minimum level of competence that should be expected of anybody who's going to write C++, and knowing how binary counting works is part of that -- so no, `n%2` is not better.

Comment: @JerryCoffin "I think there's a minimum level of competence that should be expected of anybody who's going to write C++, and knowing how binary counting works is part of that" - absolutely. It does not mean that we should intentionally write obfuscated code, though.

Comment: @H2CO3 ...and this is not doing anything of the sort.

Answer (score 6):

If I work with strings and *concise code matters a bit more than performance* (like you have in Python), then I might write just this:

```
 static const std::string pattern = "XY";
 std::cout << pattern * n; //repeat pattern n times!
```

And to support this, I would add this functionality in my string library:

```
std::string operator * (std::string const & s, size_t n)
{
   std::string result;
   while(n--) result += s;
   return result;
}
```

One you have this functionality, you can use it elsewhere also:

```
std::cout << std::string("foo") * 100; //repeat "foo" 100 times!
```

And if you have user-defined string literal, say `_s`, then just write this:

```
std::cout << "foo"_s * 15;  //too concise!!

std::cout << "XY"_s * n;  //you can use this in your case!
```

[Online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/903b1d18d58fc7b8).

Cool, isn't it?

Comment: A slight misuse of operator overloading and quite inefficient, but +1 for answering the "concise matters"-case :)

Comment: @DanielFrey: Updated with other form of concise-ness. :-)

Comment: Nice, although the [tag:optimization]-tag points more into the direction of my answer ;-P

Comment: @DanielFrey: hehe, yes. :D

Comment: Just realized: Your solution does not work properly: for `n==3`, OP wanted `"XYX"`, not `"XYXYXY"`.

Comment: @DanielFrey: Yes, I realized that long back, but then I conveniently assumed `n` is even, or if it is not even, the fix is trivial. It just makes my code a bit clumsy :(.

Comment: You can still steal my implementation... ;-)

Comment: This answer is not much faster than my original code, but it's very useful in a different area where i have a char*. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If there is a reasonable upper limit for `n`, you could use:

```
static const std::string xy = "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY";
cout << xy.substr( 0, n );
```

or, to be safe, you could add:

```
static std::string xy = "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY";
while( xy.size() < n ) xy += "XYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXYXY";
cout << xy.substr( 0, n );
```

finally, consider `cout.write( xy.c_str(), n );` if efficiency is most important for you to avoid the overhead of `substr()` copying of the result.

Comment: Interesting. I've never heard of `cout.write()` so this might come in handy in the future.